# ST_ClusterWithin logic and usage

Tags: postgis, clustering

My data."geoJson" column has EPSG 4326 and SRID undefined for some reason.

I am using dbscan as follows (with correct results):

```
ST_ClusterDBSCAN(st_transform(data."geoJson",24313),eps := 50, minPoints := 1)
```

so I am transforming the coordinate system, do I have to do the same with ST_ClusterWithin, or can I simply go ahead with:

```
ST_ClusterWithin(data."geoJson", 50)
```

to give me 50m clusters?

Furthermore, is each item in such a cluster 50m or less from ALL other items in the cluster? Am I correct in understanding that 50m is the maximum distance between the two furthermost items in the cluster?

Won't there be significant overlap if that is the case? so in that case can a single geometry be part of multiple "geometry collections"?

Comment: Please refer to the docs, they will answer your questions https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterWithin.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ST_ClusterWithin` (and the new `ST_ClusterWithinWin`) creates clusters in which each item is no further than the distance tolerance to **at least one other item** in the cluster.  Thus clusters may contain pairs of items which are further apart than the distance tolerance.

`ST_ClusterWithin` produces a *partition* of the input set into groups of "nearby" geometries.  Items are always only assigned to a single cluster.

Answer (score 3):

The logic of `ST_ClusterWithin` is identical to `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` with `minPoints := 0`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it is minPoints = 1 according to this resource: http://www.danbaston.com/posts/2016/06/02/dbscan-clustering-in-postgis.html

Comment: I think minPoints = 0 and minPoints = 1 have the same behavior, but it's been a while since I worked on this problem.